# Can't get access token by call Meteor HTTP get request

Tags: node.js, api, http, meteor

**Http token request description(Doc)**

URL: https://demo.tld/connect/token

HTTP Verb: POST

HTTP Headers:

- Authorization: Basic base64encode(clientId:clientSecret)
- Content-Type: multipart/form-data

HTTP Body:

- grant_type: client_credentials

**My requested code:**

```
try {

   let endCodeOfAuth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(clientId + ':' + clientSecret).toString('base64');

  HTTP.post("https://demo.tld/connect/token", {
       headers: {
              'Authorization': endCodeOfAuth,
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
           },
       content: 'grant_type:client_credentials'
      }, (error, res) => {

       if (res) console.log("2. res", res );
        else console.log("1. error", error);

     });
     return true;

   } catch (error) {
    return false;
}
```

Response:

```
  statusCode: 500,
   content: '',
   headers: {
    server: 'Kestrel',
     'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET',
     date: 'Mon, 01 Jun 2020 11:54:59 GMT',
     connection: 'close',
     'content-length': '0'
  },
  data: null
 }
```

Comment: Please add the endpoint's code and the error response to your question (please not as comment but edit the question).

Comment: @Jankapunkt thank you for reply. I want to know, My code are correct or have some wrong. So response data is null.

Comment: Status code 500 means there is a server error. Can you please add the server function?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I using third party api. So I did not see their function. But postman working according to their rules. But HTTP request is different. Please see their doc to above. "Http token request description(Doc)"

Comment: Are you sure your request (headers, body etc.) are exactly 1:1 the same as with your postman request?

Comment: @Jankapunkt my postman request:

```var request = require('request');
 var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'https://demo.tld/connect/token',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Basic sdY2xpZW50SWQ6Qmd1RU1yd2pNalJtZ3k1VTEyOG5ZeGFrRFZlOVo='
  },
  formData: {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) { 
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

Comment: Not the code, I mean the request itself, are you sure the actual HTTP requests are both the same? Try to use a diff tool to see if there is somewhere a type or a missing space etc.

Comment: It's solved it. let ```newForm()``` data and set header 
const FormData = require('form-data');

let data = new FormData();
data.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");

Set 'content: data' in header.